# Get PROMISE OBJECT Value IN NODEJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, promise

I have a nodejs function that returns the value of the following query. The function returns the value as an object. how do i get the value from Promise object? When i tried to print the value, it prints as  " [object Promise] "

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'true', 'false') AS MYVAL FROM MY_TABLE_STATUS WHERE ID = '100'
```

Comment: In Javascript, you get values out of a promise by using either `.then()` or `await` on the promise.  This should be thoroughly covered in any introductory article or tutorial on using promises.

Answer (score 0):

```
global.mysql = require('mysql');
global.mySqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  port:3306,
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'db_name'
});


async getData()=>{
       var myPromise = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             mySqlConnection.query("SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'true', 'false') AS MYVAL FROM MY_TABLE_STATUS WHERE ID = ?",[100],(err, result) => {
                     error ? reject(error) : resolve(results);
             });
        });
       }
   var result = await (myPromise());
   console.log('result ==',result);
   mySqlConnection.destroy();
   return result;
}
```

Comment: I am getting the below error.  Am i missing anything ??            ann@Ann-MacBook-Pro test % node test.js       
/Users/ann/Code/nodejs/test/test.js:11
async getData()=>{
      ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1018:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1066:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)